# To open the file without an extension and change its language

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

The following code (you should run it with cmd.exe) opens Sublime Text and changes language to JSON:

```
sublime_text.exe -n -w --command "set_file_type {\"syntax\": \"Packages/JavaScript/JSON.sublime-syntax\"}"
```

However, I need to slightly change its behavior. It should change the language of the opened file. The file is `README` without an extension.

```
sublime_text.exe C:\test\README -n -w --command "set_file_type {\"syntax\": \"Packages/JavaScript/JSON.sublime-syntax\"}"
```

For some reason it doesn't work. The language is still "Plain Text". What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: On windows `sublime_text.exe` and `subl.exe` are different things; you should use `subl.exe` to do things like this. Regardless of that in this case though, is Sublime already running at the point where you do this, or is this command starting it up as well?

Comment: @OdatNurd Hi. I tried it with `subl.exe` as well, it doesn't help. "is Sublime already running...?" - I tried 4 ways to use this code. 1st: ST is closed and there are no open tabs, 2nd: ST is closed and has some open tabs, 3rd: ST is open and there are no open tabs, 4rd: ST is open and there are some open tabs. The language is always "Plain Text".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try this, I see that it sets the syntax of the tab that was active before I executed the command.

This tells us, that the command supplied on the command line is executed before the file is loaded, likely because ST does this asynchronously.

For me, it's possible to get it working by using a separate invocation:

```
subl C:\test\README && subl --command "set_file_type { \"syntax\": \"Packages/JavaScript/JSON.sublime-syntax\" }"
```

Note that I'm not using `-w`, as this would wait until the file is closed before executing the command.

Also, you can set the syntax of a new file directly using the `new_file` command:

```
subl --command "new_file { \"syntax\": \"Packages/JavaScript/JSON.sublime-syntax\" }"
```

Obviously, if you want it in a new window, you can keep the `-n` argument. And if you want Sublime Text not to return control to the shell until you close the file, then you can keep the `-w` too, but from what I can see, that only works if you are opening a file, not when creating a new one. And if you use `-w`, you won't be able to change the syntax from the command line. You may be better off using a plugin like `ApplySyntax` or writing a small Python script yourself to set the file type when a file is opened with the path `C:\test\README` etc.